# ReferenceError: Discord is not defined... but it is defined/ set properly (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!!';
const fs = require ('fs');

client.commands = new Dicord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endswith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'ping') {
    client.command.get('ping').execute(messsage, args);
  } else if(command === 'twitch') {
    message.channel.send('https://www.twitch.tv/wrigglysplash');
  }

});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

This is all of the code that I am using. I do have a decent amount of experience with node.js, however, I don't see what I am doing wrong to get this error. I made sure to install Discord and require it/ make it a constant. I could just be stupid and be missing the simplest thing though.s

```
ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at /home/runner/MiltonJs/index.js:6:23
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I am using repl.it to write and execute it, but that has never been an issue in the past and shouldn't be an issue now. (I hope not)

Comment: `Dicord.Collection` should be `Discord.Collection`.

Comment: @SoullessCookie Btw you should also add `require('dotenv').config();` as well at the beginning or else the `process.env.TOKEN` will return an error because it can't find an `.env` file.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox Although it did seem to work fine before, I might as well add that anyways, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo: In line 6 you wrote `Dicord` instead of `Discord`

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!!';
const fs = require ('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endswith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'ping') {
    client.command.get('ping').execute(messsage, args);
  } else if(command === 'twitch') {
    message.channel.send('https://www.twitch.tv/wrigglysplash');
  }

});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: It fixes the issue, I checked

Comment: It might have been the guy that answered (left a comment) a bit before you.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes, typo questions will be deleted eventually so it isn't worth to answer them.